# Why do I get this compilation warning in Netbeans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, java-7

I am working on a Java-EE project involving Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and the client component is running with Java 7 Update 21. The Swing-based client was formerly based on Java 6 Update 38 until we decided to migrate to the new Java 7 Update 21.

I get the following compilation warning in Netbeans 7.3:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
```

At this point, the compilation process hangs for about 1 minute.

Btw, we still have the javaee-api-6.0.jar referenced that is provided by the Netbeans platform (I think there's no javaee-api-7.0.jar available yet?)

Does somebody know the reason for this warning and how I can get rid of it ?

Any help highly appreciated - many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It seems (I think) that the eclipseLink annotation processing for JPA is up-to-date until Java 6. You could make a Java 6 library with the JPA sources, and only there use eclipseLink annotation processing. Having a library never hurts, and later you may upgrade to Java 7 independantly.

Can't image using much Java 7 functionality in the JPA sources.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! currently I am using eclipselink-2.3.2. what do you think, would it help to upgrade to eclipselink-2.4.1 ?

Comment: No experience, but sure, seems logical.

Answer (score 3):

Java version 7 has more features as compared to Java 6. In netbeans, go to Tools-->Java Platforms and check whether your netbeans ponts to the latest version of JAVA.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my netbeans/java platforms configuration seems to be okay. there's only java 7 listed there...

Answer (score 0):

I thing You have added unwanted library,first, you have to check your library of your project and delete the unwanted files there. On the other hand, you can retry it by copying only the JFrames and Main Classes into a new Project. But One thing, You have to replace the name of package as the new name.